# How to quit an AppleScript applet that is currently looping?

Tags: loops, applescript, exit

I've modified this with suggestions from Robert K but it doesn't seem to be working. I think it has to do with the dual use of "delay 60" and "return 30". I know that delay needs to be there or it will get double triggered within the 5 minutes. As it is below, it doesn't respond to quit command so has to be forced quit.

```
on idle
    set myTime to time of (current date) as string
    repeat until myTime ≥ 75600 -- stop at 9pm local time
        
        set myTimeB to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0 --every 5 minutes
        if myTimeB then
            say "triggered"
        end if
        
        delay 60 --less than 30 may cause it to get double triggered.
    end repeat
    return 30 -- idle time (every 10 minutes)
end idle

on quit {}
    display dialog "Sure you want to quit?"
    continue quit -- quits the applet
end quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat loop of stay-open applications is **on idle** handler. Read some AppleScript guide about stay-open applications to understand better how they work. In this case, for example you should use code like this:

```
on idle
    set myTime to time of (current date)
    if myTime ≥ 75600 and myTime < 76201 then
        --do something
    end if
    return 600 -- idle time (every 10 minutes)
end idle

on quit {}
    display dialog "Sure you want to quit?"
    continue quit -- quits the applet
end quit
```

Also, note that I compare with time interval instead of time = 75600 exactly. Otherwise, your condition may never be met. You don't have to demand an accurate second hit, because we add 600 seconds idle time.

Comment: Thank you. If it's running a 5 minute loop will I need to set return 600 to something lower like 300?

Comment: Also, my script is set up to run for 24 hours starting at UTC 0 and loop every 5 minutes so I think myTime needs to stay like it was at myTime ≥ 75600. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I think I have something wrong because it's not responding to quit.

Comment: 1) Copy my script into the Script Editor **as is**, 2) replace **return 600** with **return 300** (as you desided now to loop every 5 minutes instead of 10 minutes), 3) Save it **as stay-open application** and run.

Comment: NOTE: replace **if myTime ≥ 75600 and myTime < 76201** then with **if myTime ≥ 75600 and myTime < 75901** as well.